# Error while using compute variable on SPSS

Tags: spss

I'm trying to compute a new variable on SPSS using the menu (tramsform -> compute variable) and an error message appears saying

> Text value too long for the current server locale

Do they mean the Numeric Expression I wrote (pasted below)?

If so - is there anything I can do other than making a new variable for every step in the process? Don't really want to compute 10 different variables just to make the one I need...

```
((LAB_TEST_CD = ‎‪62112‬)&(((LAB_RESULT > ‎‪8‬)&(SAMPLE_DATE < ‎‪20111103))
|((LAB_RESULT > ‎‪7)&(SAMPLE_DATE  >=  ‎‪20111103))))
|((LAB_TEST_CD = ‎‪62111)
    &(((LAB_RESULT > ‎‪30)&(SAMPLE_DATE < ‎‪20140112))|((LAB_RESULT > ‎‪7)
    &(SAMPLE_DATE  >=  ‎‪20140112))))
```

Comment: Instead of copying this to the transform menu you should edit this in a syntax window (like this: `compute yourNewVar= .....` ) and run it from there. That will make it easier to edit and might solve your problem. In general I recommend you learn to use syntax, especially if you're going to use complex calculations like this.